# JDBC driver does not support XA issue

Tags: java, jdbc, transactions, soa, xa

I am getting "JDBC driver does not support XA issue"

Error committing transaction:; nested exception is: javax.transaction.xa.XAException: JDBC driver does not support XA, hence cannot be a participant in two-phase commit.

Answer (score 3):

In the Weblogic Console, go to `Services` > `Datasources`.

Click on your datasource. Then, click on the `Transaction` tab:

- `Supports Global Transactions` should be already selected.
- Select `Emulate Two-Phase Commit`.

Save this configuration and restart the server.

Answer (score 2):

set the GlobalTransactionsProtocol attribute to LoggingLastResource (recommended) or EmulateTwoPhaseCommit for the Data Source.
This should work.

Comment: I know this answer is old, but why do you have to change the protocol to LLR ? Why doesn't the 1PC work ?

Answer (score -1):

Still you are facing this issue, please restart weblogic server & check.

Comment: This should rather be a comment.